# evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler: alternative?

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

I want to know if there is a github project that is an alternative to wkwebview's `evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler`.

The reason for this is because for my server, I've noticed that I can't call `evaluateJavaScript` from a background thread, to which Xcode tells me it can't and I have to wrap it inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`

I searched but couldn't find any thing on the topic. So I was hoping there was a way of doing this whether through a third party or way in the native API's.

Thank you.
Ali El.

Comment: If I remember correctly you can use UIWebview.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in background

Comment: I just tried it and i get a API thread checker. being called from another thread other than the main thread or web thread... and also the memory is through the roof

Comment: Yeah it is deprecated as well, just a thought...

Comment: It looks like iOS has the `jsc` command-line tool in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Resources`, and `posix_spawn`ing it seems to work in the simulator. However, I don't know whether the sandbox would block this on an actual device, and I have my doubts as to whether this would get past the App Store...

Comment: I'm hoping to release this to the store, so I'm a little weary on this method :/